# qpainter drawText text direction and size

Tags: pyside, qpainter

I have a QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene pair. I have overriden the QGraphicsView.drawBackgroud method in order to draw a rectangular grid. Everything is fine until that point, but when I try to draw the actual coordinates, using QPainter.drawText method, the resulting text is upside down. Another issue is that I dont want the text for coordinates values resize with zooming, but I havent been able to achieve this.

My view is initially scaled (1,-1).

I'm working on PySide

This is my code for drawBackground:

```
pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0))
painter.setPen(pen)
gridInterval = 10
#painter.setWorldMatrixEnabled(True)

l, r = rect.left(), rect.right()
t, b = rect.bottom(), rect.top()

dx = (r - l) / gridInterval
dy = (t - b) / gridInterval 
left = int(l) + dx / 2
bottom = int(b) + dy / 2
nx = gridInterval
ny = gridInterval
dx = (r - l) / gridInterval
dy = (t - b) / gridInterval 
myxrange = [left + i * dx for i in range(nx)]
myyrange = [bottom + j * dy for j in range(ny)]

xlabels = ["{0:.2f}".format(x) for x in myxrange]
ylabels = ["{0:.2f}".format(y) for y in myyrange]

xlines = []
for point in myxrange:
    line = QtCore.QLineF(point, t, point, b)
    xlines.append(line)

ylines = []
for point in myyrange:
    line = QtCore.QLineF(l, point, r, point)
    ylines.append(line)

painter.drawLines(xlines)
painter.drawLines(ylines)

#font = QtGui.QFont()
#font.setPointSize(20)
#painter.setFont(font)

for k, text in enumerate(xlabels):
    #painter.save()
    #painter.rotate(90)
    painter.drawText(myxrange[k], myyrange[0], text)
    #painter.rotate(-90)
    #painter.restore()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution that works for the "rotated" text. I had to rescale the painter before drawing the text and actually draw it on the translated location:

So the for loop looks like this:

```
for k, text in enumerate(xlabels):
    painter.save()
    painter.scale(1,-1)
    painter.drawText(myxrange[k], -myyrange[0], text)
    painter.restore()
```

I'm still looking for an answer to the fixed size issue.